# batch file to check openvpn connection when is online/up

Tags: vpn, batch-file, openvpn, connection

I need to check the vpn connection when is online/up with a batch file.

**Actually i use this code:**

```
PING -n 5 www.google.com|FIND /I "TTL">NUL

IF NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
Echo "Vpn Connection Is Up"
)
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
Echo "Vpn Connection Is Down"
)
```

Sometimes the ping give a non response or give a general failure response.

I would like to know that there is a better batch code alternative than the ping command.

I tried this alternative codes but do not recognize vpn when is online/up because the adapter is always in my pc installed.

**First Alternative Code:**

```
ipconfig|find /i "VPN" && GOTO startAPP || GOTO connectVPN
```

**Second Alternative Code:**

```
ipconfig|find /i "VPN"

if %errorlevle%==1 goto:connectVPN

echo Starting APP !
exit/b

:connectVPN
echo connecting to VPN
```

**Third Alternative Code:**

```
:start
cls
rasdial | find /I "%vpnname%" > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto vpndown
if errorlevel 0 goto vpnup
```

Can You recommend an alternative command to ping to be integrated into my batch code please ?

The alternatives code do not recognize when vpn connection is online, it's recognize if exist the adampter installed in my pc but i need to know when vpn is online/up (ready to go on internet).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this file: `/etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log`

I would also try looking at the output of ifconfig and checking if the adapter exists and is up or down.

Comment: I don't find this file "/etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log" in my openvpn i do not see this folder. I use openvpn 2.4.6-I602. thanks

Comment: Do you have a different log file in that folder? You can also check your global log files (i.e. `grep VPN /var/log/syslog`)

Comment: Every vpn ip have a log, i do not find a global log file. i use more vpn ip.